# Redshift table appropiate distribution key and sort key for my table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

i have a table where columns are like record_id, creation_date, active_time, inactive_time and some more data columns. as of now there are around 12M records in the table.
distinct 'record_id' (varchar(6)) values count in table is : 8M (data distribution is even on this column)
distinct 'creation_date' (date) values count in table is : 800 (data distribution is even on this column)
cluster detail - total slices are 16.

if I talk about the join of this table with other tables, it is mostly based on the columns 'record_id' and 'creation_date'. and some time active_time and inactive_time also participate in the join.

question is:-

1. what should i take as distribution_key for this table,  record_id or creation_Date ?
2. What should i take sort key ? as i said above active_time and inactive_time also participate in the joins some time, so should i include these 2 column in sort key ?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for Amazon Redshift is:

- Set the `DISTKEY` to the column most commonly used in `JOIN`
- Set the `SORTKEY` to the column most commonly used in `WHERE`

A table with 12 million rows is not very big for Redshift. Even if you get it wrong, it will run very well.

I would recommend a DISTKEY of `record_id` (since it seems to be often JOINed).

Set SORTKEY to what you normally use to limit results. It can only be one column. Redshift will store the rows in the order of the given column, and will remember the minimum and maximum values of that column in every 1MB storage block. This allows it to 'skip over' blocks that do not contain that value. This makes the queries run quickly because it can avoid disk access, which is the slowest part of any database.

See: [Amazon Redshift best practices for designing tables - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-tables-best-practices.html)

Comment: thank you john for your valuable input.
i also agree 12M record are not much for redshift, it will work fast even we choose any key, let forget this thing for some time.

Comment: Here both column 'record_id' and 'creation_date' has equal importance in join.
if i talk about average record count for single record_id is less than <2 (max to max 10 in some cases), and for creation_dt average record count ~15,000.  
so i am thinking while applying a join of this table with another table for last 2 months of creation_date. then in that case performance should be good with DIST_key as creation_date.  and sort key as compound key (creation_date, record_id). Please suggest something on this.

Comment: sample query is below.

select a.*,b.* from table_A a join
table_B b
on
a.record_id = b.record_id and
a.creation_date = b.creation_date and
a.creation date >= current_date -1;

Comment: How many Nodes and Slices are in your Redshift cluster? (See [Data warehouse system architecture - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_high_level_system_architecture.html)) The DISTKEY is used to distribute data across the slices. If you don't have many slices, then the DISTKEY doesn't matter as much since more data will be located already on the same slice. In your situation, I would suggest just picking one of them as the DISTKEY, but feel free to test each one to see for yourself which one works best. When testing, run queries twice due to caching.

Comment: Based on your sample query, I would suggest a DISTKEY of `record_id` and a SORTKEY of `creation_date` (since it is being used more like a `WHERE` than a `JOIN`). It is matching _multiple_ creation dates, so it is not suitable for a DISTKEY.

Comment: Thank you john for your valuable inputs !!